# Pandas: How to iterate over aggregated groupby

Tags: python, pandas

My task is to groupby and aggregate a DataFrame, then do something with each group (subset) of that data.

Grouping and aggregating appears to give the expected results.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).aggregate(np.sum)
```

However, I run into trouble when trying to iterate over the individual groups.

*Approach 1:*

```
for group in grouped:
    temp_data = group.iloc[:11, 3]
    # ...do some other stuff...

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

*Approach 2*

```
for name, group in grouped:
    temp_data = group.iloc[:11, 3]
    # ...do some other stuff...

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What I'd ultimately like is for each grouped/aggregated subset of data from the original DataFrame to be operated on as its own DataFrame. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: After your first line `grouped` is a DataFrame, so in your loop `group` is just the column names. The construction for iterating over groups is `for idx, group in df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']):`

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense and does work before aggregation is applied. However, the issue appears to arise when I aggregate. Aggregating the groups appears to return a string. (??)

Comment: I think you’re getting confused, when you do `for x in df` you are iterating over the names of the columns, not the dataframe